# get list of counts for items

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables symbol and rpm.

**Table Details:**
*rpm:*
Entries in rpm export symbols and consume as well.

*symbol:*
symbol table is a collection of all symbols(exported and consumed).

**Table description:**

*symbol:*
symbols table have id, name, rpm_id (maps to id of rpm table) , flag to show whether it is exported or consumed.
flag = 1; consumed
flag = 0; exported

*rpm:*
rpm table is having id, name.

**More Context:**
A symbol exported by a rpm entry is consumed many times by other rpm table entries.
Hence a symbol is enlisted in the symbol table multiple times with different id, rpm_id.

**Problem Statement:**
List exported symbols by a given rpm(given its id; say 35) and number of time each symbol is consumed by other rpm entries.

**output layout:**

> symbol.name | count(number of time this symbol is consumed)|

**Tried solution:**

> SELECT symbol.name, count(distinct symbol.rpm_id)
>
> FROM symbol, rpm
>
> WHERE symbol.flag = 0 && symbol.rpm_id = 35
>
> GROUP BY symbol.name;

but I am getting '1' in count column for each symbol, which is wrong.

**Semantic of query in question:**

First query should get all the symbols exported by given rpm.id (rpm.id = 35),
then for each resulted symbol.id in result set, it should find number of times it is consumed i.e. its count and print the count in front of that symbol.

### please suggest some way/query to get result.

thank you.

Comment: can you post structure of tables on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: you select the distinct count of your rpm_id wich is in the where (only the rpm_id 35 will be selected)... use count(symbol.id)

Comment: @silly: It show only one row, having one symbol(first one) which is exported by  rpm.id = 35 and count(of all symbols exported by rpm.id=35) in front of that single symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
select 
    rpm.id , 
    rpm.rpm , 
    count(symbols.id) 
from rpm
left join symbols on symbols.rpm_id = rpm.id
where symbols.flag = 1
group by rpm.id
```

1 is for consumed

Comment: Do you mean by rpm.name as rpm.name, right? I altered this and executed. It is showing complete count on symbol table entries. Perhaps we haven't provided the rpm.id for which we want to get symbols and their count. I test this also(giving rpm id = 35 in where clause with && operator) still it shows just one row in result and count(of total symbols exported by rpm.id = 35).

Comment: can't suggest you anything unless you provide some sample data to test